Как сделать чтобы бот выдал два разных ответа на одну команду
у меня есть бот с расписанием автобусов, он выдает из списка ближайшее время. Я сделал переменную s и p и засунул ее в ответ бота. Мне нужно чтобы бот выдавал "нет подходящего времени" когда не будет ближайшего автобуса. Как можно сделать такую же переменную для второго ответа ? или как вообще это реализовать ? Проблема в том что бот останавливается когда нет ближайшего автобуса, а запрос боту идет.
Вот сам код
from datetime import datetime
import bisect

time_list = ["6:28", "6:46", "7:14", "7:24", "7:35", "8:01", "8:23", "8:44", "9:01", 
 "9:23", "9:37", "10:11", "10:41","11:16", "11:27", "12:00", "12:31", "12:48", "13:00", 
 "13:14", "13:37", "14:04", "14:38", "14:48", "15:35", "16:00", "16:20", "16:40", 
 "16:55", "17:15", "17:45", "18:08", "18:20", "18:44", "19:35", "20:23", "21:10", 
 "22:10"]

 timeA = [datetime.strptime(temp, "%H:%M") for temp in time_list]

  date_now = datetime.now()
  now = date_now.strftime("%H:%M")
  timeB = datetime.strptime(now, "%H:%M")

  ind = bisect.bisect_right(timeA, timeB)
  if ind < len(time_list):
  s = time_list[ind]

time_list1 = ["6:00", "6:20", "6:48", "7:12", "7:34", "8:00", "8:12", "8:36", "8:50", "9:24", "9:48", "10:18", "10:42",
         "11:12", "11:48", "12:00", "12:13", "12:30", "12:50", "13:14", "13:48", "14:03", "14:48", "15:12", "15:32",
         "15:47", "16:02", "16:21", "17:00", "17:20", "17:36", "17:56", "18:30", "18:48", "19:36", "20:23", "21:23"]

 timeA1 = [datetime.strptime(temp, "%H:%M") for temp in time_list1]

 date_now = datetime.now()
 now = date_now.strftime("%H:%M")
 timeB1 = datetime.strptime(now, "%H:%M")

 ind = bisect.bisect_right(timeA1, timeB1)
 if ind < len(time_list1):
 p = time_list1[ind]

 @bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
 def get_user_text(message):
 if message.text.lower() == ('ближайший 22'):
    mess = f'Выберите остановку и напишите ее так же как написано тут: солнечный, 
 поселок'
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, mess, parse_mode='html')
 if message.text.lower() == ('солнечный'):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Ближайший в, {}'.format(s) )
 if message.text.lower() == ('поселок'):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Ближайший в, {}'.format(p) )


Что делать с ответами на мой вопрос.

Вставьте код нормально со всеми отступами внутри тройных обратных косых одинарных кавычек

from datetime import datetime
import bisect

time_list = ["6:28", "6:46", "7:14", "7:24", "7:35", "8:01", "8:23", "8:44", "9:01", 
"9:23", "9:37", "10:11", "10:41","11:16", "11:27", "12:00", "12:31", "12:48", "13:00",
"13:14", "13:37", "14:04", "14:38", "14:48", "15:35", "16:00", "16:20", "16:40",
"16:55", "17:15", "17:45", "18:08", "18:20", "18:44", "19:35", "20:23", "21:10",
"22:10"]

timeA = [datetime.strptime(temp, "%H:%M") for temp in time_list]

date_now = datetime.now()
now = date_now.strftime("%H:%M")
timeB = datetime.strptime(now, "%H:%M")

ind = bisect.bisect_right(timeA, timeB)
if ind < len(time_list):
    s = f"Ближайший в,{time_list[ind]}"
else:
    s = "нет подходящего времени"

time_list1 = ["6:00", "6:20", "6:48", "7:12", "7:34", "8:00", "8:12", "8:36", "8:50", "9:24", "9:48", "10:18", "10:42",
"11:12", "11:48", "12:00", "12:13", "12:30", "12:50", "13:14", "13:48", "14:03", "14:48", "15:12", "15:32",
"15:47", "16:02", "16:21", "17:00", "17:20", "17:36", "17:56", "18:30", "18:48", "19:36", "20:23", "21:23"]

timeA1 = [datetime.strptime(temp, "%H:%M") for temp in time_list1]

date_now = datetime.now()
now = date_now.strftime("%H:%M")
timeB1 = datetime.strptime(now, "%H:%M")

ind = bisect.bisect_right(timeA1, timeB1)
if ind < len(time_list1):
    p = f"Ближайший в,{time_list1[ind]}"
else:
    p = "нет подходящего времени"

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def get_user_text(message):
    if message.text.lower() == ('ближайший 22'):
        mess = f'Выберите остановку и напишите ее так же как написано тут: солнечный,поселок'
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, mess, parse_mode='html')
    if message.text.lower() == ('солнечный'):
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id,s)
    if message.text.lower() == ('поселок'):
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id,p)

Надо было просто добавить else в if и все норм становится

отлично это то что я и хотел

@MaksBraun вам уже не первый раз намекают на то, что ответы, которые вам помогли, нужно помечать как принятые. Да еще и плюсовать можно, в знак благодарности.

я не знаю как помечать

@MaksBraun Для того, чтобы отметить ответ принятым, нажмите на серую галку рядом с ответом. Галка станет зелёной. Это будет означать, что ответ отмечен как решение вопроса. Вы можете в любой момент снять галку или отметить ею другой ответ.Чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, проголосуйте за ответ и отметьте его как решение.
